# Reuse Github Actions self hosted runner on multiple repositories

Tags: github, ubuntu-server, github-actions

I have a Self-Hosted Github Actions runner running on my server for 1 of my repositories. But now I want to use that same runner for an other repo.

Is there a way that I can reuse that same Github Actions runner for an other repo without the need of creating a new runner?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update:**

This is possible as of 22nd of April 2020. 
You can now share runners across an organization.
This allows for repositories within your organization to use those runners.

https://github.blog/2020-04-22-github-actions-community-momentum-enterprise-capabilities-and-developer-improvements/#share-self-hosted-runners-across-an-organization

**Old Answer:**

This is not possible as of yet, according to a Github Partner:

> Currently, we have no methods to use the self-hosted runners across repositories, and also have no options to added self-hosted runners on Organization level.

Source:  https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Can-one-Github-Actions-self-hosted-runner-work-for-multiple/td-p/41465

Comment: Is there any update? are we now able to add multiple repo to config of action runner?

Comment: As of March 15th 2020, still no such option exists.

Comment: is there any workaround? using github hook or something?

Comment: @SameerRezaKhan there is a workaround. https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Self-hosted-runners-specific-to-repository/m-p/48482/highlight/true#M7182. It's not great though.

Comment: @SameerRezaKhan This is officially suported now. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. @steven

Comment: Anyone know of any good articles/blogs about how to do this with the new ability to share self-hosted runners? Saw the article, but I'm still not sure how to go about this

Comment: @BrandonMcKay You simply create/use your organization (it's free) and add self-hosted runners to it (via the organization settings).

Comment: Any way to do the same for personal repos not belonging to any organization?

Answer (score 8):

For those that want to know what I did to fix this problem. I installed multiple GitHub runners on my server with different names. Not the best solution, but the only thing thats possible now without a dirty workaround...

Comment: Honestly, not a terrible way to do it. If your repositories are exclusive, in that you can have multiple runners running concurrently and not have any conflicts (e.g. node, yarn, bundler, etc.) then I *think* this is the only way to do it. If you want/need the runner to only run job at a time (for either repository) then the best way would be to set it up as an Organization Runner and have it server multiple repositories. Please correct me if I'm wrong! :)

Answer (score 5):

We're using auto-scaled self-hosted github action runners on AWS spot instances.

We've open-sourced it: https://github.com/philips-labs/terraform-aws-github-runner

One of its creators make a blog post about it with some information about the workings: https://040code.github.io/2020/05/25/scaling-selfhosted-action-runners

Once a runner is active it can pick up multiple builds from various repositories. After a while, the idle runners are terminated. When a new workflow is triggered, a github app will create a new runner and that runner will pick up the work.

Answer (score 3):

Now the organization account can create a github runner and use it in all repositories.

[image]

Comment: is there any way for someone to do this with a personal account? I am a one man army and I have my own self-hosted runners!

Comment: @LukePighetti if you are a one man army then the organization level action runner with Default group should serve you well. As there's no permission issue in that case.